# Python setdefault not lvalue, any work-arounds?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following small program:

```
ages=[23,23,43,54,34,22,43,23]

histogram={}
for age in ages:
    if not age in histogram:
        histogram[age]=1
    else:
        histogram[age]+=1

for age,count in sorted(histogram.items()):
    print "Age: %d Number of people: %d"%(age,count)
```

It creates a simple histogram of the ages of people in a list. However, I find the double lookup in the histogram hash quite unsightly. I know hash access is basically O(1), so this isn't as inefficient as it may seem, but still...

I've tried various work-arounds, such as trying to use setdefault, but the following won't fly:

```
histogram.setdefault("age",0)+=1 #<- Incorrect
```

I know I can use defaultdict, but it changes the behaviour of the created histogram dict object, which is not what I want.

If there were a way for me to set this question to a "low priority" I would, because obviously this isn't very important. But I've been looking for a clever and/or elegant solution to this problem for a long time.

So, the question is: How to increment an integer by a key in a dict, or set it to 1 if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Your comment about efficiency is premature optimisation, but if it does matter to you then do some timings: I think you'll find that the double lookup is faster than either `setdefault` or using `Counter`. Calling a method such as `setdefault` requires a dictionary lookup to find the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular application, you should use [a `Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

ages = [23,23,43,54,34,22,43,23]

histogram = Counter(ages)

for age,count in sorted(histogram.items()):
    print "Age: %d Number of people: %d"%(age,count)
```

If you really need a `dict`, you could convert the Counter back to a dict with the `dict` constructor.

```
histogram = dict(Counter(args))
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the best answer. The answer below seems to suggest that Counter isn't any more efficient, but at least using it means that there is at least the possibility that the author of Counter will figure something out in the future, and my code will then benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This is [how `collections.Counter` does the counting](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l499), adapted to your example.

```
histogram_get = histogram.get
for age in ages:
    histogram[age] = histogram_get(age, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise the dict upfront, i.e.

```
histogram = dict(((a, 0) for a in set(ages)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
histogram.setdefault("age", [0])[0] += 1
```